# How can i make a horizontal, both directions, (as if the body was a 360 horizontal plane), scrolling body with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

How can i make a horizontal, both directions, (as if the body was a 360 horizontal plane), scrolling body with javascript? It is important that it comes back to the beggining through the scroll, either way you go.

I made a jsfiddle.

```
      var main = document.querySelectorAll("main_div");
          var container  = document.querySelectorAll("object_container");

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

 function myFunction() {
if (window.scrollBy(80000, 0) > 0 || window.scrollBy(80000, 0) > 0) {
   document.container.createElement(container);
 } else if (window.scrollBy(0, 0) < 0 || window.scrollBy(0, 0) < 0) {
   document.container.prepend(container);
   }
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/camilongeira/ckhd17q5/24/#&togetherjs=7tT1ILHRvg

The background image and the objects are on the *main_div*, and i was trying to make a function that triggered the main_div to repeat itself when you scrolled to the end of it, but couldnt manage and also dont know if it would make sense because cant make elements appear to the left side from the beggining.

I hope i am being clear enough... i am quite new in this community and understand people dont want to waste their time, but have been going around this for sometime and there are some close solution but nothing really does what i want...

Thanks!

Comment: instead of infitely repeating, you should rather think of it like a unwrapped cube, so there would be 6 "surfaces" with a height and width of 100vh/100vw and when scrolled to end you rather reset the scrolled amount to the start, i guess its pretty tough though and you better go off using a 3d-library like three-js

Comment: Yes i don´t want to go into that because i think it can be solved in an easier way @johnSmith , or do you think this is the only way something like this could work? I have seen vertical up and down 360 scrollers that don´t go into 3d.